# app-inventor need help running multiple timers

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to run 40 or more countdown timers in a single app for a game I play.

I have managed to get one timer block to run but if I run two or more, the timers interfere with each other? 
I know that the timers would not be accurate to the millisecond but that is not an issue.

I don't have much experience at this sorry, and I have not had any straight forward answers from anyone yet.I have asked so, could someone make it a simple as possible please thank you.

Comment: You should post code, and be more specific about what you are coding in? What language are you using? This may actually be a question for the Game Developement SE http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: @ckpepper02 the language is [App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/), see also the tag..., probably this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/programming-with-app-inventor/taeIhFtdWRg/SDZcfLcwCX8J) can help ...

Answer (score 0):

App Inventor doesn't have the capabilities yet to run that many timers, they might make it so that your apps can handle that many. Are all the timers on one page of the game or are they on different levels?